# Fourier series, $a_0/2$ term

Tags: calculus, fourier-series

can somebody please show where $\frac{a_0}{2}$ comes from. I don't understand where the "2" comes from.
Thank you in advance. Below is a screenshot from a calculus book:

[image]

Comment: It is labeled that way in order to make the formula for the first term related to the average value of the function the series represents, that is $$\frac12 a_0 = \frac12 \frac1p \int_{-p}^p f(t) dt = f_{ave}$$
It is related to symmetry this way as odd functions wont have a constant term ($a_0$ really is essentially just the $n=0$ cosine term).

Comment: ok, so far I get that $a_0$ is the cos(0) term, when the first sum is incremented once. But!
When I increment the sum by one I don't have 1/2 anywhere :(
i.e.: $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \cdot cos(\frac{n \pi x}{p}) \rightarrow a_0+\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \cdot cos(\frac{n \pi x}{p})$$

Comment: Nothing stops you from redefining the constant term to absorb the half, some authors do this, the remaining coefficients depend on n in nontrivial ways and the most general way to write them is $a_n$ or $b_n$